# How to capture server error when rendering of NextJS

Tags: next.js, elastic-apm

## Context

I'm using [elastic-apm-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elastic-apm-node) for monitoring Next server, however, I can not capture the Uncaught exception on server (error happens when rendering component on server, not the error at `getServerSideProps`)

- [ErrorBoundary](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling#handling-client-errors) approach will not work, because it captures the error at client.
- [Custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) also does not work

```js
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);

      setTransactionName(req.url);
      await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      captureInternalError(res);
    } catch (err) {
      captureError(err);

      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end('internal server error');
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      captureError(err);
      process.exit(1);
    })
```

the `try--catch` and `.once('error'` do not be triggered when error happened at rendering component on server.

- Catch at `getInitialProps` of `_error` page is what is needed, but having some problems

  - it can not run server code even I check to execute on server only

```js
getInitialProps = async ({ res, err, locale }) => {
  if(!!res) { // only execute on server
    import('elastic-apm-node').then(({captureError}) => {
      logger.error(error); // custom logger
      captureError(err);
    })
  }
})
```

it throws error  module `fs` not found (fs was using by elastic-apm-node)

- Even we have `_error`, but every Uncaught exception happens, there is an error log stacktrade by Next with multiple lines which is not good for logging. (we have a custom logger to log 1 line already)

### Questions

1. is there a way to capture all errors on server
2. can we disable auto log stacktrade for Uncaught exception?